# d3.js data source for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I am currently writing a rails app that will display charts. The front end will make ajax calls to the backend for data to display a chart (unless this is a bad plan).

I have been playing with d3.js offline, and I can't seem to find a way to make json data work. I can load data from a tsv file, but not a json formatted variable.

1. is there a way to get d3.js to load data from an ajax call?
2. do I have to write the data to a TSV file and then read it?

Comment: What's wrong with [d3.json](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json)?

Comment: I didn't know that wasn't the thing.